# Include Holidays count in working days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timedate](
    [TimeKey] [date] NULL,
    [DayName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Holiday] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [BusinessDays] [int] NULL,
    [QuarterNumber] [int] NULL,
    [CalenderWeek] [int] NULL,
    [MonthNo] [int] NULL,
    [CalenderMonth] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CalenderMonthAbbrevation] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CalenderMonthWeekNumber] [int] NULL,
    [CalenderDayabbrevation] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


 insert into timedate values ('2017-09-25','Monday','',1,3,'',9,'September','SEP',4,'MON')
 GO
 insert into timedate values ('2017-09-26','Tuesday','',1,3,'',9,'September','SEP',4,'Tue')
 GO
 insert into timedate values ('2017-09-27','Wednesday','',1,3,'',9,'September','SEP',4,'Wed')
 GO
 insert into timedate values ('2017-09-28','Thursday','',1,3,'',9,'September','SEP',4,'Thu')
 GO
 insert into timedate values ('2017-09-29','Friday','',1,3,'',9,'September','SEP',4,'Fri')
 GO
insert into timedate values ('2017-09-30','saturday','',0,4,'',10,'October','OCT',1,'Sat')
 GO
insert into timedate values ('2017-10-1','Sunday','',0,4,'',10,'October','OCT',1,'SUn')
 GO
```

i want to get a result like when Businessdays=0 then previousworkingday=1
when 2 businessdays in a month=0 then previous woringday=2

Note: 
1.Businessdays=0 defines holiday
2.businessdays=1 defines woring day.

Comment: You can simply do it by using `CASE`, just google it and try to do it by yourself first.

Comment: Hi Susang, Tried with case statements i can able to print by using weekdays like when monday then 1 ... when friday then 2 , but i need when tuesday is holiday i have to assign value 2 to monday. Thanks

Comment: @chaitanya: Kindly share sample data for all the cases along with desired output

Comment: Hi Zarruq, E.g: Monday Businessday=1 then value=1 , Tuesday Businessday=0 then update value to monday=2 .                         
 TimeKey    DayName BusinessDays Output
25-09-2017 Monday 1                  1
26-09-2017 Tuesday 1                  1
27-09-2017Wednesday 1                  1
28-09-2017 Thursday 1                  1           
29-09-2017 Friday 1                  2
02-10-2017 Monday 1                  1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking in to your sample data and desired output, One way could be to use `ANSI` standard `OLAP` functions to check if following `BusinessDays = 0` and `BusinessDays` `not in sat/sun` then `current BusinessDays +1` as below.

```
SELECT t.TimeKey,
       t.DayName,
       t.BusinessDays,
       CASE
           WHEN min(BusinessDays) over(
                                       ORDER BY TimeKey ROWS BETWEEN 1 following AND 1 following) = 0
                AND BusinessDays <> 0
                AND DayName NOT IN ('saturday',
                                    'sunday') THEN BusinessDays + 1
           ELSE BusinessDays
       END AS CalcValue
FROM timedate t;
```

OR `LEAD()`.

```
SELECT t.TimeKey,
       t.DayName,
       t.BusinessDays,
       CASE
           WHEN lead(BusinessDays) over(
                                       ORDER BY TimeKey ) = 0
                AND BusinessDays <> 0
                AND DayName NOT IN ('saturday',
                                    'sunday') THEN BusinessDays + 1
           ELSE BusinessDays
       END AS CalcValue
FROM timedate t;
```

**Result:**

```
TimeKey                DayName       BusinessDays   CalcValue
-------------------------------------------------------------
25.09.2017 00:00:00    Monday        1              2
26.09.2017 00:00:00    Tuesday       0              0
27.09.2017 00:00:00    Wednesday     1              1
28.09.2017 00:00:00    Thursday      1              1
29.09.2017 00:00:00    Friday        1              2
30.09.2017 00:00:00    saturday      0              0
01.10.2017 00:00:00    Sunday        0              0
02.10.2017 00:00:00    Monday        1              1
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/RET42557)**

Comment: LEAD() isn't proprietary

Comment: Thanks Zarruq .   TimeKey DayName BusinessDays CalcValue
25-09-2017 Monday 1 1
26-09-2017 Tuesday 1 2
27-09-2017 Wednesday 0 1
28-09-2017 Thursday 0 0
29-09-2017 Friday 1 2
30-09-2017 saturday 0 0
01-10-2017 Sunday 0 0
02-10-2017 Monday 1 1
03-10-2017 Tuesday 1 1
04-10-2017 Wednesday 1 1
05-10-2017 Thursday 1 1
06-10-2017 Friday 1 2
07-10-2017 saturday 0 0
08-10-2017 Sunday 0 0
The above logic works for single holiday in mid week also when there is no change in month we have to show 3 for Friday (includes Saturday & Sunday)

Comment: @chaitanya: You can extend the logic by introducing new `case` statements  to include any newly coming scenarios :-)

Comment: @Zarruq Thanks Zarruq.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.TimeKey,t.DayName,t.BusinessDays, case when(select count(1) from  timedate bd where bd.BusinessDays=0 and bd.TimeKey in (dateadd(day,2, t.timekey) ,  dateadd(day,1, t.timekey) )  and  [monthNo]=  datepart(mm,dateadd(day,2, t.timekey))and  [monthNo]=  datepart(mm,dateadd(day,1, t.timekey)))=2 then 3
when(select count(1) from  timedate bd where bd.BusinessDays=0 and (dateadd(day,1, t.timekey) =bd.TimeKey)and
 [monthNo]=  datepart(mm,dateadd(day,1, t.timekey)) and bd.BusinessDays<>t.BusinessDays )=1then 2  when t.BusinessDays=0 then 0else 1 end as valsFROM timedate t;
```